# cannot find proper file encoding for the libbgi.a file from the graphics library for C

Tags: c, file, encoding, bgi

I was trying to open the libbgi.a file from the graphics.h library for C, but I keep getting the error "File was loaded in the wrong encoding". No matter which encoding I use it just wont open properly (https://github.com/SagarGaniga/Graphics-Library)

Answer (score 0):

The file `libbgi.a` is a precompiled library. This means that it is a binary file, not a text file.

You should not attempt to open a binary file as a text file. There is no text encoding with which you could open it.

Libraries are intended to be passed to the [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) when building a program.